# UIPickerView shows question marks instead of UIImageView and UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uipickerview

I am working on a Poker-iPhone-Application. Everything works just fine but I would like to make a change: At the moment I have a UIPickerView with two Components and it works really good:

**relevant working code**

```
cardColor = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"not known",@"Spades", @"Hearts", @"Diamonds", @"Clubs", nil]; // ColorArray
cardValue = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"not known",@"Ace",@"King", @"Queen",@"Jack",@"Ten",@"Nine",@"Eight",@"Seven",@"Six",@"Five",@"Four", @"Three",@"Two",nil]; //FaceValueArray

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIPickerView DataSource



- (NSInteger) numberOfComponentsInPickerView: (UIPickerView *) pickerView {
    return 2;

}

- (NSInteger) pickerView: (UIPickerView *)pickerView
 numberOfRowsInComponent: (NSInteger) component {

    if(component == CARD_COLOR)
        return [self.cardColor count];
    else
        return [self.cardValue count];

}

- (NSString *) pickerView: (UIPickerView *) pickerView
              titleForRow: (NSInteger) row forComponent: (NSInteger) component {
    if(component == CARD_COLOR)
        return [self.cardColor objectAtIndex:row];
    else
        return [self.cardValue objectAtIndex:row];
}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIPickerView Delegate


- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if(component == CARD_COLOR) return 130.00;

    else return 190.00; 

}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:
(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSLog(@"picked row: %i, component: %i", row, component);

    if (component == CARD_COLOR) {


        NSLog(@"the string: %@", [self.cardColor objectAtIndex:row]);
        short color;
        if ([self.cardColor objectAtIndex:row]==@"not known") {
            color=INVALID;
        }
        if ([self.cardColor objectAtIndex:row]==@"Spades") {
            color=SPADES_VALUE;
        }
        if ([self.cardColor objectAtIndex:row]==@"Hearts") {
            color=HEARTS_VALUE;
        }
        if ([self.cardColor objectAtIndex:row]==@"Diamonds") {
            color=DIAMONDS_VALUE;
        }
        if ([self.cardColor objectAtIndex:row]==@"Clubs") {
            color=CLUBS_VALUE;
        }

        NSLog(@"value %i",color);




    }
    if (component == CARD_VALUE) {

        NSLog(@"the string: %@", [self.cardValue objectAtIndex:row]);
        short value;


        if ([self.cardValue objectAtIndex:row]==@"not known") {
            value=INVALID;

        }
        if ([self.cardValue objectAtIndex:row]==@"Ace") {
            value=ACE_VALUE;

        }
        if ([self.cardValue objectAtIndex:row]==@"King") {
            value=KING_VALUE;

        }
        if ([self.cardValue objectAtIndex:row]==@"Queen") {
            value=QUEEN_VALUE;

        }
        if ([self.cardValue objectAtIndex:row]==@"Jack") {
            value=JACK_VALUE;

        }
        if ([self.cardValue objectAtIndex:row]==@"Ten") {
            value=TEN_VALUE;

        }
        if ([self.cardValue objectAtIndex:row]==@"Nine") {
            value=NINE_VALUE;

        }
        if ([self.cardValue objectAtIndex:row]==@"Eight") {
            value=EIGHT_VALUE;

        }
        if ([self.cardValue objectAtIndex:row]==@"Seven") {
            value=SEVEN_VALUE;

        }
        if ([self.cardValue objectAtIndex:row]==@"Six") {
            value=SIX_VALUE;

        }
        if ([self.cardValue objectAtIndex:row]==@"Five") {
            value=FIVE_VALUE;

        }
        if ([self.cardValue objectAtIndex:row]==@"Four") {
            value=FOUR_VALUE;

        }
        if ([self.cardValue objectAtIndex:row]==@"Three") {
            value=THREE_VALUE;

        }
        if ([self.cardValue objectAtIndex:row]==@"Two") {
            value=TWO_VALUE;
        }

        NSLog(@"value %i",value);

    }
```

When I run my project with the code above, it looks like this:

[image: working implementation without UIImageViews]

The actual problem is, that I would prefer to replace the NSStrings at the indexes 1 till 4 with UIImageViews. Some days ago I read that I can achieve this with replacing all NSStrings by UILabels and the use

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
```

instead of

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

.

So I changed my code into to this:

**relevant not-working code**

```
UILabel * colorPickerUnknownLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 145, 45)];
    colorPickerUnknownLbl.text=@"not known";
    [colorPickerUnknownLbl setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
    colorPickerUnknownLbl.opaque=NO;
    colorPickerUnknownLbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    colorPickerUnknownLbl.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    colorPickerUnknownLbl.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0];
    UIImage * colorPicker1Img = [UIImage imageNamed: @"picker_color-01.png"];
    UIImage * colorPicker2Img = [UIImage imageNamed: @"picker_color-02.png"];
    UIImage * colorPicker3Img = [UIImage imageNamed: @"picker_color-03.png"];
    UIImage * colorPicker4Img = [UIImage imageNamed: @"picker_color-04.png"];

    self.cardColor = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:colorPickerUnknownLbl ,colorPicker1Img,colorPicker2Img, colorPicker3Img, colorPicker4Img, nil]; // ColorArray
    self.cardValue = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"not known",@"Ace",@"King", @"Queen",@"Jack",@"Ten",@"Nine",@"Eight",@"Seven",@"Six",@"Five",@"Four", @"Three",@"Two",nil]; //FaceValueArray

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIPickerView DataSource



- (NSInteger) numberOfComponentsInPickerView: (UIPickerView *) pickerView {
    return 2;

}

- (NSInteger) pickerView: (UIPickerView *)pickerView
 numberOfRowsInComponent: (NSInteger) component {

    if(component == CARD_COLOR)
        return [self.cardColor count];
    else
        return [self.cardValue count];

}

- (UIView *) pickerView: (UIPickerView *) pickerView
              viewForRow: (NSInteger) row forComponent: (NSInteger) component {
    if(component == CARD_COLOR)
        if(row==0)return [self.cardColor objectAtIndex:row];
        else {
            UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self.cardColor objectAtIndex:row]];
            return imageView;
        }
    else {
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 145, 45)];

    //For right alignment of text,You can set the UITextAlignmentRight of the label.  
    //No need to set alignment to UITextAlignmentLeft because it is defaulted to picker data display behavior.

    [label setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    label.opaque=NO;
    label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
    label.font = font;
    [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.cardValue objectAtIndex:row]]];
        return label;
    }
}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIPickerView Delegate


- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if(component == CARD_COLOR) return 130.00; 

    else return 190.00; 

}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:
(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSLog(@"picked row: %i, component: %i", row, component);

    if (component == CARD_COLOR) {


        //NSLog(@"the string: %@", [self.cardColor objectAtIndex:row]);
        short color;
        if ([self.cardColor objectAtIndex:row]==[cardColor objectAtIndex:0]) {
            color=INVALID;
        }
        if ([self.cardColor objectAtIndex:row]==[cardColor objectAtIndex:1]) {
            color=SPADES_VALUE;
        }
        if ([self.cardColor objectAtIndex:row]==[cardColor objectAtIndex:2]) {
            color=HEARTS_VALUE;
        }
        if ([self.cardColor objectAtIndex:row]==[cardColor objectAtIndex:3]) {
            color=DIAMONDS_VALUE;
        }
        if ([self.cardColor objectAtIndex:row]==[cardColor objectAtIndex:4]) {
            color=CLUBS_VALUE;
        }

        NSLog(@"value %i",color);





    }
    if (component == CARD_VALUE) {

        NSLog(@"the string: %@", [self.cardValue objectAtIndex:row]);
        short value;


        if ([self.cardValue objectAtIndex:row]==@"not known") {
            value=INVALID;

        }
        if ([self.cardValue objectAtIndex:row]==@"Ace") {
            value=ACE_VALUE;

        }
        if ([self.cardValue objectAtIndex:row]==@"King") {
            value=KING_VALUE;

        }
        if ([self.cardValue objectAtIndex:row]==@"Queen") {
            value=QUEEN_VALUE;

        }
        if ([self.cardValue objectAtIndex:row]==@"Jack") {
            value=JACK_VALUE;

        }
        if ([self.cardValue objectAtIndex:row]==@"Ten") {
            value=TEN_VALUE;

        }
        if ([self.cardValue objectAtIndex:row]==@"Nine") {
            value=NINE_VALUE;

        }
        if ([self.cardValue objectAtIndex:row]==@"Eight") {
            value=EIGHT_VALUE;

        }
        if ([self.cardValue objectAtIndex:row]==@"Seven") {
            value=SEVEN_VALUE;

        }
        if ([self.cardValue objectAtIndex:row]==@"Six") {
            value=SIX_VALUE;

        }
        if ([self.cardValue objectAtIndex:row]==@"Five") {
            value=FIVE_VALUE;

        }
        if ([self.cardValue objectAtIndex:row]==@"Four") {
            value=FOUR_VALUE;

        }
        if ([self.cardValue objectAtIndex:row]==@"Three") {
            value=THREE_VALUE;

        }
        if ([self.cardValue objectAtIndex:row]==@"Two") {
            value=TWO_VALUE;
        }

        NSLog(@"value %i",value);

    }
```

When I run my project with the not-working code it looks like this:

[image: not-working implementation with (not appearing) UIImages]

I am working on this since hours, but I can't find the bugs. Does someone of you have an idea or another solution for my problem?

Comment: maybe your problem in this line: `if(row==0)return [self.cardColor objectAtIndex:row];` ? You return `UIImage`, but it's not a `UIView` subclass.

Comment: I think, that I create a UIView in these lines. 
'if(component == CARD_COLOR)
        if(row==0)return [self.cardColor objectAtIndex:row];
        else {
            UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self.cardColor objectAtIndex:row]];
            return imageView;
        }'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `viewForRow` delegate method is named incorrectly (the `reusingView` parameter is missing).

Instead of this:

```
- (UIView *) pickerView: (UIPickerView *) pickerView
          viewForRow: (NSInteger) row forComponent: (NSInteger) component {
```

it should be this:

```
- (UIView *) pickerView: (UIPickerView *) pickerView 
          viewForRow: (NSInteger) row forComponent: (NSInteger) component 
          reusingView:(UIView *)view {
```